# Queues en Livewire no funcionan

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Estoy tratando de agilizar las cargas de imágenes usando *queues* en *Livewire* y me muestra el siguiente error:

> Serialization of 'Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile' is not allowed

Mi código:

```
foreach($this->imagenes as $imagen){
            ProcesarImagenes::dispatch($imagen, $propiedadId);
        }
```

Job:

```
 protected $imagen;
    protected $propiedadId;

    public function __construct($imagen, $propiedadId)
    {
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
        $this->propiedadId = $propiedadId;
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        $imagen = $this->imagen;
        $propiedadId = $this->propiedadId;

        $nombre = Str::random(10) . $imagen->getClientOriginalName();
        $ruta = public_path() . '\imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre;

        //make recibe la imagen
        Image::make($imagen)
            ->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })
        ->save($ruta);

        $img = imgPropiedades::create([
            'url' => '/imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre,
            'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
        ]);


    }
```

Agradezco si me pueden brindar una ayuda de si es posible utilizar *Queues* en *Livewire*.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era la serialización dado que espera una clase, por lo tanto lo convertí en array y funciona perfecto.

```
$galeria = [
                'imagenesGaleria' => $pathGaleria->getRealPath(),
                'ruta' => $ruta
            ];

ProcesarImagenes::dispatch($galeria);
```